# Python Pandas 'head' attribute not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a quick script playing around with python and pandas to work with some data, however, I am trying to print the `'head'` but when I do I get an error. Any ideas what might be the problem?

`AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'head'`

```
import pandas as pd
my_file_location = "whatever.xlsx"
dfs = pd.read_excel(my_file_location, sheet_name=None)

print(dfs.head())
```

Answer (score 3):

You are loading a workbook with multiple sheets and you pass `sheet_name = None` to `pd.read_excel()` which tells it to load all of the sheets in the workbook and return them as a dictionary. Either select one of the sheets from the dictionary, or pass the name of the sheet to `pd.read_excel()`.

For example, to show all sheets:

```
import pandas as pd
my_file_location = "whatever.xlsx"
dfs = pd.read_excel(my_file_location, sheet_name=None)
for n,d in dfs.items():
  print('Sheet Name:{}'.format(n))
  print(d.head())
```

or to select sheet named "somename":

```
import pandas as pd
my_file_location = "whatever.xlsx"
dfs = pd.read_excel(my_file_location, sheet_name='somename')
print(d.head())
```

More options are explained in the [documentation for `pandas.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: I will also add that, if you know your .xlsx is only 1 sheet, you can use 'dfs[0]' instead of looping through.

Comment: Weird when I try to add the sheet name I get an error saying that there is no sheet with that name.

Answer (score 0):

And to shorten Craig's solution:

```
import pandas as pd
my_file_location = "whatever.xlsx"
dfs = pd.read_excel(my_file_location, sheet_name=None)
[(print('Sheet Name:{}'.format(n)),print(d.head())) for n,d in dfs.items()]
```

Use `print` in list comprehension.

The problem with your code is because `dfs` are a sequence of object's that ave an `head` attribute :-) (funny way of explaining)

If your sheets only contain one sheet:

```
...
print(dfs[0].head())
```

Comment: Using `print` in a list comprehension is kind of unnecessary. Not sure if makes sense :)

Comment: @RafaelC It's clear that it is unnecessary, i am doing that for length :-) hhihhihhahha